# How do I hook up my computer speakers to my Playstation 2?

Tags: speakers, ps2

The speakers have a cable with 3.5 mm TRS plug; the cable is directly going into one the speaker boxes, so it cannot be detached. The A/V cable coming from the console has an S-Video Mini-DIN plug and a pair of audio cinch plugs. The S-Video is plugged into the monitor.

What are my options? I strongly prefer things I would be able to order from geizhals.at (local hardware price comparison).

Comment: This is console or electronics related. Irrelevant of the requirement of the OP to use PC Speakers, this question is outside the scope of SuperUser as per the FAQ and will remain closed. I can see **no** hardware or software problem within this question, and would be just as well asked on a Audio/Video support site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **2 RCA female to 3.5mm Female Audio Adapter Converter Cable**

[image]

Comment: PS2 doesn't have a headphone jack, but only the proprietary combined A/V and a separate digital out. I'll look for this adapter cable.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a one of thing, I simply recommend you take a look for converter boxes and/or connectors.

However, If you have good speakers and many devices, look at getting an AV Receiver, you can just plug everything in to them which can have a load of different input and outputs and it can do all the hard work for you.

[image]

Comment: ahhh, Marantz ... the memories! but i think the term "geizhals" refers to a "very tight person", so a big 'boombox' is probably out of the equation, however, i like the sight of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to grab something [like this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=female+rca+to+female+headphone+jack&cid=12037070188082563730&sa=title#p) and then a female stereo-mini to female stereo-mini converter. Works like a charm for me, when I hook my console up to headphones or my PC speakers. I got mine at Radio Shack, but I imagine they're available many places.

Edited to say I [found a link](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102672&filterName=Cable+type&filterValue=Couplers) to the coupler I was refering to.